# Can I load custom jsm modules in bootstrap.js of a restartless add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless, jsm

I'm trying to load a custom module in a restartless add-on, using the following:

**chrome/content/modules/Test.jsm**:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [ 'Test' ];

let Test = {};
```

**chrome.manifest**:

```
content   test  chrome/content/
```

**bootstrap.js**:

```
const Cu = Components.utils;

// Tried this first, but figured perhaps chrome directives aren't loaded here yet
// let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;

function install() {
  let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;
}
function uninstall() {
  let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;
}
function startup() {
  let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;
}
function shutdown() {
  let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;
}
```

However, I get the following types of WARN messages (this one was for `shutdown()`, but basically identical for all functions and in the earlier attempt in the global scope):

> 1409229174591 addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method
>   shutdown on test@extensions.codifier.nl: [Exception... "Component
>   returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)
>   [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"  nsresult: "0x80070057
>   (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
>   file:///test/bootstrap.js :: shutdown :: line 21"  data: no] Stack
>   trace: shutdown()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm ->
>   file:///test/bootstrap.js:21 <
>   XPI_callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4232
>   <
>   XPI_updateAddonDisabledState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4347
>   <
>   AddonWrapper_userDisabledSetter()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:6647
>   < uninstall()@extensions.xml:1541 < oncommand()@about:addons:1 <

Are `chrome.manifest` directives not yet available in `bootstrap.js`? Or is what I am attempting some kind of security violation, perhaps? Or am I simply doing something trivially wrong?

---

What I was hoping to achieve, is that I could do something like the following:

**chrome/content/modules/Test.jsm**:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [ 'Test' ];

let Test = {
    install: function( data, reason ) {
    },

    /* etc */

    bootstrap: function( context ) {
        context.install = this.install;
        context.uninstall = this.uninstall;
        context.startup = this.startup;
        context.shutdown = this.shutdown;
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.js**:

```
const Cu = Components.utils;
Cu.import( 'chrome://test/modules/Test.jsm' );
Test.bootstrap( this );
```

Perhaps it's a bit over the top to begin with, but I just kind of like the idea of hiding implementations in modules and/or objects and keeping `bootstrap.js` super clean.

If you happen to have suggestions on how to achieve this by other means: I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can your path is wrong though.

Just do this:

```
let test = Cu.import( 'chrome://test/content/modules/Test.jsm', {} ).Test;
```

notice the `/content/`

You don't have to do the `.Test` unless you want the lower case `test` to hold it. You can just do:

```
Cu.import( 'chrome://test/content/modules/Test.jsm');
```

and use as `Test.blah` where blah is whatever is in the JSM module.

This code can go anywhere, it does not have to be in the `install` function.

Make sure to unload the custom JSM modules or else it can lead to zombie compartments which is bad for memory. Read here:

- last paragraph here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Common_causes_of_memory_leaks_in_extensions
- more reading but optional: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Zombie_compartments

Comment: Thank you for your answer Noitidart! I will try this out later, but I trust that it works. But please help me understand, if you will: why is /<namespace>/**content**/modules needed here, while that was not needed when I was using a `resource://` namespace in a non-restartless version, for instance. (Unfortunately, resources are not allowed in bootstrapped add-ons, as you probably know already). I mean, isn't the directory `content` already defined in the directive `content test chrome/content/`? Why do I still need to add it in the url? And where can I find out more about this mechanism?

Comment: PS.: I was aware of the possible memory leaks already. But thank you anyway, for the heads-up!

Comment: It's just how chrome.manifest stuff works they made it that way :)

Comment: Resource paths dont were not made to be like chrome paths which are registered via manifest. I think this was api developer decision.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion now. However, the module is only available in `startup()` and `shutdown()`,  unfortunately; not in the global scope, or the other functions. In those it warns: `No chrome package registered for chrome://test/content/modules/Test.jsm`. I was hoping I could completely delegate bootstrapping to my jsm module, by doing something like `Test.bootstrap( this );`, but that is a no-go now, it seems. I'll update my question with an example of what I was hoping to achieve. Perhaps you, or anybody else, still has some ideas of how to achieve something similar.

Comment: Thats interesting I didnt know that. I thought once chrome.manifest registerd you can use it wheever in your boostrap.js, ok thats a new one for me. thxnk you';re right i had done some experimenting and startup is the earliest you can call it: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9045387

Answer (score 1):

Beyond @Noitidart's answer, you don't have to use chrome.manifest' and register a content package if your only concern is how to import your module.

```js
function install(data, reason) {
  Components.utils.import(data.resourceURI.spec + "relative/path/to/your/module.jsm");

}
```

Comment: To do this way, make sure its in the `install` or `startup` functions, they both have this first argument of `data` (well so do shutdown and uninstall but thats more important for `unloading` the module). Or if you want to do it outside the install function, set global var or somethign to `data` arg of install. See here for whats contained in the data object: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999#comment-1120821

Comment: Ah, this is good to know as well. Thank you. I prefer the solution that I can use outside of the functions as well, at the moment though.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of a way to make this work in global scope, would you? (Probably not, since it makes sense to only have `resourceURI.spec` available in the functions), but please see my questions edits, for what I was hoping to achieve. Perhaps you have some more ideas. Thank you.

Comment: If your aim is to keep `bootstrap.js` minimal you might be satisfied with an [`include()` function](https://gist.github.com/erikvold/1024242) utilizing `loadSubScript`

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I found out about `__SCRIPT_URI_SPEC__` (which he utilizes) as well, and *that* was the kind of thing I was hoping to find. If put a reference to it in your answer, I'll mark is as best.